# Laravel 5.4 / 5.5 File uploading app to be deployed on the Google App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

When using Laravel on GAE, I found [this](https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5) method to override the default filesystem class and the filesystem helpers in the framework. 
https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5

But, the problem is, this only supports for Laravel 5.1 and 4.

I need to write a file uploading app using Laravel 5.5 / 5.4 and deploy it to the GAE. The uploaded files should be saved to the Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

Where do I need to add the configurations of the Cloud Storage Bucket's credentials and, where to specify that I'm using the Google Cloud Storage Bucket system?

I've gone through so many tutorials and, forums. But no concrete solution for this problem.

I went through the [config/filesystems.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php). But didn't find any supportive information in the docs regarding the Google Cloud Platform.

Please let me know whether I need to modify the filesystem helper functions also, like the `storage_path()`.

Or, will the framework automatically map to the storage bucket and provide me with the relative paths if configured properly.

Comment: have you checked [GAE's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php)?

Comment: Yes. Went through all the tutorials. There are solutions and even PHP classes written if I'm going in the normal way. But no any specific doc or community doc for Laravel 5.4 / 5.5 when it comes to file uploading.